# Time field In grails domain class

Tags: grails

I m working in a grails project. i m using kendo grid in my application. i need to create a domain class named "StatTimings" which contains two time field startTime and endTime. I cant use "Date" data type for those two variable coz the time format i need is hh:mm.
I dont want to install any plugin for this.
 this is my domain for now:

```
class StatTimings{

???? startTime
???? endTime
Date date
AutoPosting autoPosting
Status status

static constraints = {
}

enum Status{ACTIVE,INACTIVE}
enum AutoPosting{SERVICE_CHARGE,STAT_CHARGES,BOTH}
```

}

Is there any way I can make my field to accept time only?

Answer (score 3):

To make it easy to persist and bind (from HTTP params) instances of this class, I'd represent each time as two integer fields and add some helper method like `getStartTime()` and `getEndTime()`. You might want to change these helpers to return a `Date` instead of a `String` (with the day part thereof set to today) if you need to do something like calculating the difference between the start and end time.

```
class StatTimings {

  static transients = ['startTime', 'endTime']

  Integer startHours
  Integer startMins

  Integer endHours
  Integer endMins

  private String formatTime(Integer hours, Integer mins) {
    String formattedHours = hours < 10 ? "0$hours" : hours.toString()
    String formattedMins = mins < 10 ? "0$mins" : mins.toString()
    "$formattedHours:$formattedMins"
  }

  String getStartTime() {
    formatTime(startHours, startMins)          
  }

  String getEndTime() {
    formatTime(endHours, endMins)
  }

  static constraints = {
    startHours range: 0..23
    endHours range: 0..23

    startMins range: 0..59
    endMins range: 0..59

    // TODO: add a custom validator that checks the end time is after start time
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use Date and convert it in the `getStartTime()` method to the format you need with the help of `SimpleDateFormat`. This way you ignore the date part of it.

```
class StatTimings {
    ...

    def getStartTime() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm").format(this.startTime);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The java.sql.Time class subclasses java.util.Date and it makes almost the same thing and it adds a custom toString implementation as below :

```
public String toString () {

    int hour = super.getHours();
    int minute = super.getMinutes();
    int second = super.getSeconds();
    String hourString;
    String minuteString;
    String secondString;

    if (hour < 10) {
        hourString = "0" + hour;
    } else {        
        hourString = Integer.toString(hour);
    }
    if (minute < 10) {
        minuteString = "0" + minute;
    } else {        
        minuteString = Integer.toString(minute);
    }
    if (second < 10) {
        secondString = "0" + second;
    } else {        
        secondString = Integer.toString(second);
    }
    return (hourString + ":" + minuteString + ":" + secondString);
}
```

So I guess that you could add dynamically a method to Date class on bootstrap and invoke it when needed.

You can see the complete source [here](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/java/sql/Time.java.html).